# How can I set %user% and %pass% for a link? (BATCH)

Tags: html, batch-file, echo, var

today I'm searching an answer for: "How can I set %user% and %pass% for a link?"

My batch code:

```
echo off
set /p %user%=Username: 
set /p %pass%=Password:
start "" http://website.com/login?username=%user%&password=%pass%
```

If I do this, I got redirected on website but the link is: http://website.com/login?username=/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't include the percent signs (`%`) when `SET`ing your variables. So your code should look like this:

```
@ECHO off
SET /p user=Username: 
SET /p pass=Password: 
start "" "http://website.com/login?username=%user%&password=%pass%"
```

Note that I included a space after `Username:` and `Password:` so when you start typing, there you don't type right next to the colon.